# Autofill my author field with foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to autofill my user foreign key in my note project with authentication in django. I tried, but it's not working and asking that owner is required field. Please, help! Thanks in an advance.

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.owner = request.user
            instance.save()
    context = {
    'tasks':tasks,
    'form':form,
        }
    return render(request, 'list.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
 class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Share your `TaskForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you fill in the owner yourself, it makes no sense to specify the owner as a form field. You thus should exclude it, and let this be handled by the view. The form thus looks like:

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        exclude = ['owner']
```

If no `ModelForm` will need to specify the owner, you can mark the field as non-editable:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    # …
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False
    )
    # …
```